# Looking for some help on how to multiply two lists in Applescript

Tags: applescript

My question has two parts.  The first involves the simple multiplication of lists.  ListZero is (1,2,3) and ListOne is (4,5,6).  I'm looking for Applescript code that will multiply the corresponding positions in each list (I know, not technically multiplying the lists) and return ListTwo (4,10,18).

What I'm really looking for is a subroutine that multiplies a number of lists by ListZero in the manner described above, and replaces each list with it's product, like so:

set ListZero to (1,2,3)

set ListOne to (4,5,6)

set ListTwo to (7,8,9)

set ListOne to ListOne*ListZero

set ListTwo to ListTwo*ListZero

I'm very new to Applescript and haven't figured out subroutines yet.  I did Google this problem extensively before asking it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see you're looking for:

> set listOne to subroutine(listOne, listZero)

But in AppleScript when you want to update a list you can just send an list to a subroutine and update the list without extra setters and returning a newly created list. Also I've added a check to make sure that list 1 is equal or longer than list 2. If list 1 is longer than list 2 it only multiplies the items in list 1 whose index is also a valid index in list 2.

```
set ListZero to {1, 2, 3}
set ListOne to {4, 5, 6}
set ListTwo to {7, 8, 9}

multiplyWithList(ListOne, ListZero)
multiplyWithList(ListTwo, ListZero)

on multiplyWithList(l1, l2)
    set lc1 to count l1
    set lc2 to count l2

    --determine the amount of repeats
    if lc1 > lc2 then
        set maxRepeats to lc2
    else
        set maxRepeats to lc1
    end if

    --update the contents of the list
    repeat with i from 1 to maxRepeats
        set item i of l1 to (item i of l1) * (item i of l2)
    end repeat
    return
end multiplyWithList
```